# Scrap asin on amazon webpage with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

Anyone know how to make for to scrap asin on this part of source code please?
Asin is always in same part of sourcecode on webpage product.

[image]

I've try:

```
asin_n = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[@class='.prodDetAttrValue'])"))).text
```

And

```
asin_n = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "(//td[@class='.prodDetAttrValue'])"))).text
```

And

```
asin_n = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='a-size-base prodDetAttrValue']"))).text
```

And

```
asin_n = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.a-size-base.prodDetAttrValue').text
```

But not work, anyone know how to make for scrap asin on this part please?
Thanks for reply, bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`prodDetAttrValue`* is one of the classname but there are other classnames as well. So you need to use `contains()` instead and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH* and `prodDetAttrValue` *class*:

  ```
  asin_n = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//th[contains(., 'ASIN')]//following::td[contains(@class, 'prodDetAttrValue')]"))).text
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and complete *class*:

  ```
  asin_n = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//th[contains(., 'ASIN')]//following::td[@class='a-size-base prodDetAttrValue']"))).text
  ```

Comment: Thanks for answer @DebanjanB. Please see my answers for errors..

Comment: Thanks for answer @DebanjanB.
I have somes errors with your codes: for the 3 first parts, bad word is out. For the last, timeoutexception is out. You know where is the error on your code please ? Sorry for answer ans thanks for help!

Comment: @JohnDoe Let's discuss the issue in details within [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Ok, i ve put my request on you selenium room ;), thx

Comment: @JohnDoe Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help given! Everything is working perfectly now!